# How to diappear default text of Password Textbox On Java Script?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox

```
<asp:TextBox TextMode="Password" ID="TxtBx_Password" runat="server" Width="175px" Text="Password" ForeColor="Gray" 
                    onblur="WaterMarkPwd(this, event);" onfocus="WaterMarkPwd(this, event);"></asp:TextBox>
```

i am using this password text box and use WaterMarkPwd js method as shown below,

```
<script type ="text/javascript">

function WaterMarkPwd(txtpwd, event) 
{
    var defaultText = "Password";

    // Condition to check textbox length and event type
    if (txtpwd .value.length == 0 & event.type == "blur") 
    {
        //if condition true then setting text color and 
        //default text in textbox
        txtpwd .style.color = "Gray";
        txtpwd .value = defaultText;
    }
    // Condition to check textbox value and event type
    if (txtpwd .value == defaultText & event.type == "focus") 
    {
        txtpwd .style.color = "black";
        txtpwd .value = "";
    }
 }
</script>
```

problem is that if i apply this to textbox having text mode="text" then it works fine but when i chang it to textmode="password" then it shows encrypted text as i set it in method `defaultText = "Password";`

how to resolve it Hopes for your suggestions

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder

Comment: @ALL thanks for your Suggestions i have done it with jquery using water mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't concerned about compatibility, you can use the `placeholder` attribute to specify a watermark for your input.

Unfortunately, there is no way to make a `password` type field show actual text. What you *can* do is change your approach and use an overlay element that displays the watermark. Hide this whenever the input is focused.

Here is a demonstration of this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/tPtJR/

Comment: how using this "               <asp:TextBox TextMode="Password" ID="TxtBx_Password" runat="server" Width="175px" Text="Password" ForeColor="Gray" 
                    onblur="WaterMarkPwd(this, event);" onfocus="WaterMarkPwd(this, event);"></asp:TextBox>"

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to use:  **[Placeholder Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_textarea_placeholder.asp)**

```
<asp:TextBox TextMode="Password" ID="TxtBx_Password" runat="server" Width="175px"
Text="Password" Placeholder="Password"></asp:TextBox>
```

### [Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KCjZC/)

OR You can use **[Watermark plugin for jQuery](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/)** with the working **[example](http://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/282/)**

Comment: means i have to use place holder for the password that user will enter? then how to show default "Password" that would vanish on click ?

Comment: That will be possible with the `JQeury Watermark plug-in` (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/) @SyedRaza

Answer (score 0):

Just change your function to this and it will work

```
<script type ="text/javascript">

function WaterMarkPwd(txtpwd, event) 
{
    var defaultText = "Password";

    // Condition to check textbox length and event type
    if (txtpwd.value.length == 0 & event.type == "blur") 
    {
        //if condition true then setting text color and 
        //default text in textbox
        txtPwd.type = "text";
        txtpwd.style.color = "Gray";
        txtpwd.value = defaultText;
    }
    // Condition to check textbox value and event type
    if (txtpwd.value == defaultText & event.type == "focus") 
    {
        txtPwd.type = "password";
        txtpwd.style.color = "black";
        txtpwd.value = "";
    }
 }
</script>
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g8bRL/) for this

I have added two lines, first in your if part

```
txtPwd.type = "text";
```

and second in your else part

```
txtPwd.type = "password";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtBx_Password" CssClass="txt2" TextMode="Password" value="Password"      runat="server" onfocus="this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value == ''){ this.value ='Password';}"></asp:TextBox>
```

you can use above syntax and put your watermark text in value property